# 80's Scholastic book with a hand that was like a cactus coming out of the sand on the cover

Tags: story-identification, books

It was about a western town being taken over like body snatchers.  Does anyone remember a scholastic book with a hand that was like a cactus coming out of the sand on the cover it was from the 80's?